# Label origin location in Swift

Tags: swift, position, label

I'd like to add a label into a container in Swift.  I know how to add a label's center location, but I'd like to position it in my container view based on the top left corner of the label.  How can I do that?

IE: I want the top left corner of the label to be positioned 10 right, and 40 down from my containers top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
    label.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrign, width, height)
```